# randint method returns the same value on each execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, python-multithreading, seed

in the below code i am trying to learn how to use threads with synchronization. as shown below in the code i generate a thread every 3 seconds an a random number is passed to
the method isNumPrime(...) to check if the generated number is prime or not.
the problems i am facing are

1-the output i receive every time i run the code is the same. please have a look at the output below. the same random numbers are generated every time i press ctrl+f5
is

```
        thread_1 = threading.Thread(group = None, target = self.isNumPrime, 
        name='Thread_1', args = (), kwargs=dict(targetNum=randint(0,100)), 
        daemon = None)
```

indeed generates random nmbers`?? because what i am getting is not randomly generated numbers. i expect to receive differently generated numbers each time i press
ctrl+f5

2-given the output belwo, why i am receiving repeated output of "in loop: targetNum: xx"?? it must be displayed once for each single iteration with a number from range of
(3,targetNum)

**code**:

```
import threading
import logging
import time
from random import seed
from random import randint

class ThreadsWithSync(threading.Thread):

    def __new__(cls):
    """
    For object creation
    """
    print("cls: %s"%(cls))
    #cls.onCreateObject()
    instance = super(ThreadsWithSync, cls).__new__(cls)
    #print("instace: %s"%(instance.__repr__)) #activate this line whenever an informative and descriprtive text about the instance is needed to be displayed
    return instance
    
    def __init__(self):
    """
    For object initialization
    """
    #print("self: %s"%(self)) 
    threading.Thread.__init__(self) #to initialize the super class
    print("self: %s"%(self))
    seed(1)

    @classmethod
    def onCreateObject(cls):
    """
    This will be invoked once the creation procedure of the object begins.
    """

    def __repr__(self):
    """
    similar to toString in Java
    """
    return "\n__class__: " + repr(self.__class__) +"\n__new__:" + repr(self.__new__) + "\n__str__: " + repr(self.__str__) + "\n__sizeof__: " + repr(self.__sizeof__)
    
    def isNumPrime(self, targetNum):
    
    if targetNum == 0 or targetNum == 1:
        print("targetNum passed to method, will return false: %s"%(targetNum))
        return False

    if targetNum == 2:
        print("targetNum passed to method will return true: %s"%(targetNum))
        return True

    isPrim = True
    for i in range(3,targetNum):
        print("in loop: targetNum: %s"%(targetNum)) 
        if targetNum % i == 0:
            isPrim = False
            break
    print("is %s a prime : %s"%(targetNum, isPrim)) 
    return isPrim

    def spawnThread(self):
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        self.main()

    def main(self):
    while True:
        thread_1 = threading.Thread(group = None, target = self.isNumPrime, name='Thread_1', args = (), kwargs=dict(targetNum=randint(0,100)), daemon = None)
        #thread_2 = threading.Thread(group = None, target = self.isNumPrime, name='Thread_2', args = (), kwargs=dict(targetNum=randint(0,100)), daemon = None)
        thread_1.start()
        #thread_2.start()
        time.sleep(3)

t1 = ThreadsWithSync()
t1.spawnThread()
```

**output**:

```
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
in loop: targetNum: 17
is 17 a prime : True
in loop: targetNum: 72
is 72 a prime : False
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
is 97 a prime : True
in loop: targetNum: 8
in loop: targetNum: 8
is 8 a prime : False
in loop: targetNum: 32
in loop: targetNum: 32
is 32 a prime : False
in loop: targetNum: 15
is 15 a prime : False
in loop: targetNum: 63
is 63 a prime : False
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
...
...
... 
...
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
in loop: targetNum: 97
is 97 a prime : True
in loop: targetNum: 57
```

Comment: does it work if you don't set a seed in __init__?

Comment: @Jonas would you please explain to me how seed works??iwill read about it but to know more please

Comment: You use `seed(1)` to ensure the same random result, it should be fine if you remove it. As for the second question it happens because you print it inside of the for loop

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you initialize the seed the same way, you get the same numbers every time. Don't call `seed(1)` at all.

As for printing targetNum each time - perhaps you shouldn't print it inside the loop.

Comment: any logical reason why the same line is repeated inside thhe loop

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, remove the `1` from your `seed()` call. Just leave it empty `seed()`.

As for why it's repeating `targetNum`, it's because you tell it to print `targetNum`. :) Try printing `i` instead:

```
print("in loop: targetNum: %s"%(i))
```